Using Subquery or INNER JOIN
Item 2 of the challenge 2 of this Lab from Microsoft SQL Server Team, is as follows:
Challenge 1: retrieve product price information
AdventureWorks products each have a standard cost price that indicates the cost of manufacturing the product, and a list price that indicates the recommended selling price for the product. This data is stored in the SalesLT.Product table. Whenever a product is ordered, the actual unit price at which it was sold is also recorded in the SalesLT.SalesOrderDetail table. You must use subqueries to compare the cost and list prices for each product with the unit prices charged in each sale.

Retrieve products whose list price is higher than the average unit price.
Retrieve the product ID, name, and list price for each product where the list price is higher than the average unit price for all products that have been sold.

Retrieve Products with a list price of 100 or more that have been sold for less than 100.
Retrieve the product ID, name, and list price for each product where the list price is 100 or more, and the product has been sold for less than 100.


A solution (provided on the same link above) for the above challenge, they have presented with the following query that returns 7 records:
 SELECT ProductID, Name, ListPrice
 FROM SalesLT.Product
 WHERE ProductID IN (SELECT ProductID
                     FROM SalesLT.SalesOrderDetail
                     WHERE UnitPrice < 100.00)
   AND ListPrice >= 100.00
 ORDER BY ProductID;




ProductID
Name
ListPrice




810
HL Mountain Handlebars
120.27


813
HL Road Handlebars
120.27


876
Hitch Rack - 4-Bike
120


894
Rear Derailleur
121.46


907
Rear Brakes
106.5


948
Front Brakes
106.5


996
HL Bottom Bracket
121.49



But, with the same search criteria, my own following query returns 27 records (shown below) where the list prices >=100 and UnitPrice < 100:
Question: Why the solution suggested by Microsoft Lab is correct, and what I am doing is not correct:
SELECT p.ProductID, p.Name, p.ListPrice, s.UnitPrice
FROM SalesLT.Product p
JOIN SalesLT.SalesOrderDetail s ON p.ProductID = s.ProductID  
WHERE p.ListPrice >= 100.00
  AND s.UnitPrice < 100.00
ORDER BY ProductID;




ProductID
Name
ListPrice
UnitPrice




810
HL Mountain Handlebars
120.27
72.162


810
HL Mountain Handlebars
120.27
72.162


810
HL Mountain Handlebars
120.27
72.162


813
HL Road Handlebars
120.27
72.162


813
HL Road Handlebars
120.27
72.162


813
HL Road Handlebars
120.27
72.162


876
Hitch Rack - 4-Bike
120.00
72.00


876
Hitch Rack - 4-Bike
120.00
72.00


876
Hitch Rack - 4-Bike
120.00
72.00


876
Hitch Rack - 4-Bike
120.00
72.00


876
Hitch Rack - 4-Bike
120.00
72.00


876
Hitch Rack - 4-Bike
120.00
72.00


876
Hitch Rack - 4-Bike
120.00
72.00


876
Hitch Rack - 4-Bike
120.00
72.00


894
Rear Derailleur
121.46
72.876


894
Rear Derailleur
121.46
72.876


907
Rear Brakes
106.50
63.90


948
Front Brakes
106.50
63.90


948
Front Brakes
106.50
63.90


948
Front Brakes
106.50
63.90


948
Front Brakes
106.50
63.90


948
Front Brakes
106.50
63.90


948
Front Brakes
106.50
63.90


948
Front Brakes
106.50
63.90


996
HL Bottom Bracket
121.49
72.894


996
HL Bottom Bracket
121.49
72.894


996
HL Bottom Bracket
121.49
72.894


996
HL Bottom Bracket
121.49
72.894




it is easy in the teams query you reduce the number of produktids and then you reduce the number by the ListPrice , your querys must add the conditions to the on clause

First, let's be a little pedantic and consider the difference between what the task asked from you and what you did instead. The task asked you to use subselect, with the main select querying SalesLT.Product and the subselect querying SalesLT.SalesOrderDetail. Instead of doing as the task instructed you, you did a join. You could technically achieve the goal of the task with a join too, but you need to follow the instructions and, if you are being asked to use a subquery, then do so.
Second, the logical error that you committed is that when you join SalesLt.Product with SalesLT.SalesOrderDetail, then you join all matches, so if you have a product that was sold 8 times, then you will get 8 pairs and consequently you will have 8 records corresponding to that product instead of 1 (see ProductID 876 for example), which would have been the result if you followed the instruction and would have used a subquery. But, to achieve the same with a join, you can do a group by, that is, you merge your multiple product-sales tuples into singular records, exactly one record for each product that has a single match:
SELECT p.ProductID, p.Name, p.ListPrice
FROM SalesLT.Product p
JOIN SalesLT.SalesOrderDetail s ON p.ProductID = s.ProductID  
WHERE p.ListPrice >= 100.00
  AND s.UnitPrice < 100.00
GROUP BY p.ProductID, p.Name, p.ListPrice
ORDER BY ProductID;

Third, your join and their subselect is not optimal, as they will search for all pairs instead of a single example. EXISTS search for a single match in the subselect and, if found a match, stops searching for a new one, whereas IN finds ALL matches and therefore takes more time and in our case we are only interested in EXISTS, so:
 SELECT ProductID, Name, ListPrice
 FROM SalesLT.Product
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT SalesLT.SalesOrderDetail.ProductID
               FROM SalesLT.SalesOrderDetail
               WHERE UnitPrice < 100.00 AND SalesLT.SalesOrderDetail.ProductID = SalesLT.Product.ProductID)
   AND ListPrice >= 100.00
 ORDER BY ProductID;

Fourth, the first task has not been discussed. It will look somewhat similarly to their subselect:
 SELECT ProductID, Name, ListPrice
 FROM SalesLT.Product
 WHERE ListPrice > (SELECT AVG(UnitPrice)
                    FROM SalesLT.SalesOrderDetail
                    WHERE SalesLT.Product.ProductID = SalesLT.SalesOrderDetail.ProductID)
ORDER BY ProductID;


Good explanation - specifically on IN Vs. EXISTS. I learned something.

@nam happy to help!
